# Intellij IDEA ignores SDKMAN!'s Kotlin installation

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA ignores SDKMAN!'s Kotlin installation and I want it to stop because whenever I have to use Kotlin in a project, it downloads everything again.

Is there an easy way to tell Intellij or Gradle to look for any Kotlin installation on PATH before trying to pull everything from the Internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the versin of IntelliJ IDEA? Starting from 2020.1, IntelliJ IDEA is able to detect installed JDKs from SDKMAN and suggest them when adding a new JDK.

Comment: It's the latest one, 2022.1 I think. It detects the JDK alright. What I meant was the Koltin toolchain that I also installed with SDKMAN.

Comment: Not sure we are detecting Kotlin SDK in SDKMAN. Please create a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTIJ